# От какой точки отсчитывается свойство Left в браузере?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Мне нужно точно рассчитывать свойство left для повернутого по кругу блока. Везде в описаниях свойства left написано, что оно отсчитывается от левого края элемента до левого края родителя/окна, но от какой именно точки идёт отсчет?

Comment: Смотря какой `position` у самого элемента и его родителя или предка.

Comment: Вы не поняли вопрос.  Я спрашиваю, от какой точки левого края отсчитывается. От верхнего левого угла, от середины левой стороны, от нижнего левого угла. Как мне правильно позиционировать трансформированный посредством rotate элемент

Comment: Если у вас top: 0 тогда от верхнего
Если у вас top: 50% от центра
Если у вас bottom: 0 от нижнего

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду "от верхнего угла родителя", но я-то спрашиваю, от какой точки на левом краю дочернего элемента отсчитывается

Comment: @НиколайШляпников: Вы понимаете, что `position` с `top-right-bottom-left` и `transform` с `transform-origin` - это совершенно разные вещи? Это же основы, первые страницы любого учебника HTML/CSS.

Comment: Я про transform-origin и не говорил, но да, мне нужна именно эта точка, но применимая для top-left-right-bottom. Какая она у них?

Comment: @НиколайШляпников Можете код предоставить и в нем указать что вас конкретно интересует, так будет легче

Comment: может быть, вы ищете `element.getBoundingClientRect().left`? вот такая конструкция выдаст число в пикселях, которое будет указывать на самую левую точку отображения объекта, в зависимости от угла поворота это может быть верхняя или нижняя точка.

Comment: `left` и `top` отсчитываются от родителя как если бы он был системой координат, то есть вращение родителя учитывается. Но вращение дочернего элемента в расчёт не берётся. То есть эти свойства к дочернему элементу применяются как-бы до его вращения. Если вращается только дочерний, то эти свойства сместят не повёрнутый дочерний элемент как обычный любой другой элемент, и уже потом он повернётся.